# convert date time from EU time zone to PST

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz, rfc3339

i have a list of datetimes in EU time zone:

```
[u'2014-11-01T09:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-02T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-03T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-04T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-05T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-06T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-07T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-08T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-09T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-10T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-11T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-12T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-13T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-14T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-15T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-16T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-17T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-18T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-19T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-20T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-21T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-22T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-23T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-24T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-25T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-26T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-27T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-28T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-29T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-30T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-12-01T00:00:00+01:00']
```

How do i convert each of them to PST time zone?

Comment: Consider using [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) or [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) with the `America/Los_Angeles` time zone.  (Dateutil will also help with parsing.)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
from pytz import timezone
import pytz
from dateutil.parser import parse

l = [u'2014-11-01T09:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-02T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-03T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-04T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-05T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-06T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-07T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-08T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-09T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-10T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-11T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-12T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-13T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-14T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-15T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-16T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-17T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-18T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-19T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-20T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-21T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-22T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-23T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-24T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-25T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-26T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-27T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-28T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-29T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-11-30T00:00:00+01:00', u'2014-12-01T00:00:00+01:00']
amsterdam = timezone('Europe/Amsterdam')
pst = timezone('US/Pacific')
[parse(d).replace(tzinfo=amsterdam).astimezone(pst) for d in l]
```

Comment: don't use `.replace(tzinfo=amsterdam)`. `'Europe/Amsterdam'` has multiple utc offsets at different times. `.replace()` method chooses the wrong utc offset

Answer (score 0):

There are two independent tasks:

1. parse rfc 3339 date/time format into an aware datetime object

   ```
   >>> from dateutil.parser import parse
   >>> aware_dt = parse('2014-11-01T09:00:00+01:00')
   >>> aware_dt
   datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 1, 9, 0, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 3600))
   ```
2. convert it to `America/Los_Angeles` timezone

   ```
   >>> import pytz
   >>> tz = pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles')
   >>> tz.normalize(aware_dt.astimezone(tz))
   datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 1, 1, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/Los_Angeles' PDT-1 day, 17:00:00 DST>)
   ```